# Downvoted but question stayed at zero

Tags: support, reputation, voting

My question was downvoted but, it still listed the question at 0. I lost rep and am just curious if this was a bug.

Question:
[image]

Question List:

[image]

Comment: In chrome and firefox? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58308064/prevent-title-from-repeating/58308085?noredirect=1#comment102978186_58308085

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390179/578411

Comment: Likely not caching. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390233/1288408

Comment: Yeah it looks like a "feature" undergoing A/B testing. Unfortunately there's no exception for your own questions so you can't actually see your own question's score unless your rep is high enough that you can show the up/down votes. Rene's link explains the experiment.

Comment: [Ok. Experiment is off while we fix bugs. Thanks!- Shog9 yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question#comment732985_390179) nonetheless will be continued later. now I am wondering if the viewers of these *exposing* questions affect the experimental data.

Comment: @ankii Are you sure that second link is correct?

Comment: @ankii is the experiment off now?

Comment: [Yup, it's back on @TylerH- Shog9 5hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question#comment733352_390179)

Comment: Closed as off-topic but you can only know that it was "off-topic" after receiving the answer...

Comment: @faintsignal No, it was known that this was off-topic otherwise, through the posts on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an experiment that's currently being done on Stack Overflow. Downvotes aren't shown on posts with a score of less than one.

This applies to answers, too.

Here's the popup when voting on the post (I've only ever gotten it on questions):

[image]

Here's an example:

[image]

With expanded votecard:

[image]

See [New popup message when voting on a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question/390179#390179) for more details.

Comment: I get it, but I think it would be better to freeze the score at -1 instead of zero. The two browse very differently -- no votes vs a quashed pile on.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Can't help it. Bring it up with Shog if it bothers you (and note that for some users, it is frozen at -1).