# Why is my downvote hidden?

Tags: discussion, voting

Just got the following banner:

[image: Thanks for your vote! Your vote has been recorded and it affects this post's ranking. Since this post's score is below 0, your vote will not be displayed.]

What is this, and what does it mean, and why?

Comment: The Welcome Wagon strikes again.

Comment: This is an experiment that's currently being done on Stack Overflow. Downvotes aren't shown on posts with a score of less than one.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/new-popup-message-when-voting-on-a-question-answer
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334832/downvoted-but-question-stayed-at-zero

Comment: @divibisan Oh for god's sake

Comment: There’s apparently a userscript that disables it, though I haven’t tried it myself: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390255/8366499

Comment: [Coddling](https://www.google.com/search?q=coddling).

Comment: It’s only on SO, so far as I know, and is definitely not affecting the -1000 score Meta posts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an A/B experiment that's currently being done on Stack Overflow. For some randomly selected users, downvotes aren't shown on posts with a score of less than one. You can still see the true score by clicking the vote score, even if you don’t have >1k rep.

Here’s [Shog9’s post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390179/8366499) on it:

> We are conducting a two-week experiment to understand how the voting
>   user interface impacts question answering and editing.
>
> - The effects of this experiment are superficial - only the displayed score is affected.
> - You will only see this if you are logged into the site.
> - Depending on which experimental group you're in, you may see one of a number of changes to post scores, or no change at all.
> - Group membership is assigned by account. Anyone may end up in any group, *and should stay there*.
> - You can see the real up/down vote counts at any time by clicking the score while viewing a post - **even if you haven't earned [the
>     Established User
>     privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)**.
> - Search results will render differently too, but score-based operators and sorts work normally (on the actual score)
>
> You will see the user interface revert to normal behavior on October
>   23rd.

Comment: I guess they're trying to see whether they can prevent "pile-on downvotes" on absolute trash questions because said downvotes don't feel very "welcoming" to the absolute trash question author

Comment: Another justification I’ve seen for this is that it feels useless trying to improve a massively downvoted post. If the score is hidden, people might be more willing to take the time to fix it.

Comment: In my experience such questions are almost always unsalvageable anyway but hey

Comment: Yeah, I have no inside knowledge, just some things I’ve heard. Based on the recent chaos, though, I’m personally going to applaud any efforts to do research *before* making a change.

Comment: _For some randomly selected users_ - shouldn't these users know about it?

Comment: @ChristineH.Richards They do - via the banner

Comment: @ChristineH.Richards I’m not a UX designer, but my understanding is that a key part of A/B testing is randomly assigning people to groups and not highlighting the changes to prevent biasing the results

Comment: My problem with this is that we're in the middle of a massive shift in the site's demographics (read: lots of key people reducing or ending their contributions), be it temporary or otherwise. Perhaps not the best time to draw conclusions from how people operate the site.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean that they are part of the experiment. You apparently didn't know that and that banner isn't helpful either ;-)

Comment: @ChristineH.Richards Oh granted, it doesn't explain it fully ^_^ But as a result of it I've found out the answer quite quickly

Comment: @VictorStafusa Thanks for fixing that error. The correct info is that when Jon Skeet clicks the vote score, he sees the ultimate final score of that post at the End of Days

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If they are trying to prevent pile on downvotes they are failing miserably. If you don't see downvote on absolute trash, of course you will downvote. I made experiment of my own and about third of the questions I downvoted in last two days, I usually would not, because they already had enough downvotes.

Comment: @HerMajesty Interesting - you shouldn't have been holding back on voting just because other people also voted - your goal should have been "up 1" or "down 1" or "no opinion", not "I want to help this post reach X final score" :( Maybe this experiment is good then if it helps people vote responsibly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if question is at -3 there is no reason to go further down. Also, not down voting there leaves me a vote to use on another horrible post, that didn't received any.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC What do you mean "no reason"? I don't think you understand voting and scores. A score of -5 means "at least five people thought this question was not useful". If you come along and you are number six and agree with that assessment, then the score becomes -6. So now we know the new situation. That's the "reason".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have to mention that I am always voting on the content of the post (up or down). But, I will add unnecessary downvotes. I don't have problem in downvoting heavily upvoted post nor upvoting heavily downvoted post if my assessment of the post is different from others.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit One of the reasons is to give chance OP to improve. -3 is enough to be moderated, going beyond that may be too much.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC Casting a vote does not take anyway anyone's chance to improve. Failing to cast a vote may prevent them from realising that they need to. There's a reason all of this is in place. Don't play games on top of it: just cast your vote!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In theory, no. In practice it might. -3 is big enough signal that something is wrong.