# How are old post edits from question banned reviewed?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, post-ban

I just got question banned from Stack Overflow this afternoon, sadly. I read through the FAQ on that, and it suggests editing old posts to improve them.

My first question is: How exactly is that credited? I mean, it seems unlikely that someone who downvoted a question a long time ago would for-no-reason-at-all revisit it months later, notice the edit, and remove/change the downvote. So are moderators tasked with reviewing old question edits just for this, or is there some other process?

It looks like the number to the left of the question was the number of upvotes; on StackOverflow (but not here) the number of downvotes only displays when you click it. That's why it didn't match my actual reputation change.

Yes, this link ([What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)) is what I meant by the FAQ. But it didn't explain how edits to old posts are credited; so I wanted to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So are moderators tasked with reviewing old question edits just for this, or is there some other process?

No, but editing your old posts will bump them to the home / active page. So they would be reviewed by the users seeing them.

Comment: @J.D. There is A/B experiment going on that does not show real question score https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334832/downvoted-but-question-stayed-at-zero